# Check download progress while away

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus, digital-distribution

I started downloading three games yesterday so I left the PS4 in Rest Mode. 
Now I'm at work and I'd like to see the progress but going to https://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com/#!/en-us/download/queue results in an empty list...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you start the download from your console it will only show the progress from your console.

The only way to view the download progress from the PlayStation website is to push the download from there. Once you have selected to push a download from there the web site will display if the software is waiting to download or in the process of downloading.

Comment: Tha'ts exactly the problem: the queue is empty but the PS4 was actually downloading three games o.O

Comment: So wait, if you go to the PS4, it shows these games with download progress bars? Did you push the downloads from the website or start them directly from the console? This is sounding like you started them from the console, in which case nothing will be shown on the website either-way.

Comment: To add to that... the only way you'll be able to monitor progress is to second screen to your PS4, say from a Vita system.

Comment: Got it: the problem is that I started every download on the console. If you write it as an answer I will accept it ;)

Comment: I reworked the answer to account for both situations.